# SQL Command not properly ended?

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00933, table-alias

I am using a SQL statement with a Temporary relation, and am getting the error `ORA-009933: SQL command not properly ended`

I don't see anything wrong with the statement, so any assistance is greatly appreciated. The statement is:

```
SELECT Temp.name,
       Temp.AvgSalary
FROM   (SELECT A.aid,
               A.aname       AS name,
               AVG(E.salary) AS AvgSalary
        FROM   Aircraft A,
               Certified C,
               Employees E) AS Temp;
```

Thanks

Comment: really? no `join` conditions and no `group by`?

Comment: You are right, I do need a `group by`. Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

oracle does not support `as` for table aliases, only for column aliases and they are optional for that use => delete all `as` keywords ;)

Comment: By this, for clarification, I found I could do `SELECT LNAME || ', ' || FNAME, ORG FROM myTable` instead.  I had been doing something like this: `SELECT (SELECT LNAME || ', ' || FNAME FROM myTable AS NAME), ORG FROM myTable`, and this latter format with the subquery it turned out I didn't even need was causing this `SQL Command not properly ended` error, for me.

Answer (score 8):

You shouldn't put the AS temp. When putting alias to a table (or subquery) you should only write the alias. This should work:

```
SELECT Temp.name, Temp.AvgSalary 
FROM ( SELECT A.aid, A.aname AS name, AVG(E.salary) AS AvgSalary 
       FROM Aircraft A, Certified C, Employees E)  Temp;
```

Best regards,