# Using Aliases in SQL

Tags: sql, aliases

I use the following code, but I am trying to understand Aliases, I get an error with this code "SQL command not properly ended", line 2

```
SELECT student.lastname, student.firstname
FROM student AS Student_Name
INNER JOIN memberof ON (Student_Name.SID = memberof.studentid)
INNER JOIN studentgroup ON (memberof.groupid = studentgroup.gid)
GROUP BY Student_Name.lastname , Student_Name.firstname 
HAVING COUNT(memberof.groupid) >= 2
```

Comment: If you are using an alias, use it always: `SELECT Student_Name.lastname, Student_Name.firstname
FROM student AS Student_Name ...`

Comment: Don't you also need an aggregate in the select clause?

Comment: @ChaosPandion: No. All selected columns are also in the group by clause

Comment: What db engine are you using?

Comment: Down voted for not using a tag to help define context - for example letting us know that this was for Oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking that you are using Oracle which apparently does not support the as keyword for table aliases.

```
SELECT s.lastname, 
       s.firstname
FROM student s
INNER JOIN memberof 
    ON s.SID = memberof.studentid
INNER JOIN studentgroup 
    ON memberof.groupid = studentgroup.gid
GROUP BY s.lastname, 
         s.firstname 
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

**MYSQL:**

If you use an alias you need to always refer to that table using its alias. Genrally I use aliases to shorten my names so that I don't have to type as much

```
SELECT s.lastname, s.firstname
FROM student AS s 
INNER JOIN memberof ON (s.SID = memberof.studentid)
INNER JOIN studentgroup ON (memberof.groupid = studentgroup.gid)
GROUP BY s.lastname , s.firstname 
HAVING COUNT(memberof.groupid) >= 2
```

"s" may be too short depening on the context of your code , but you get the idea

**ORACLE**

Oracle does not support **AS** for table aliases, only for column aliases : 
[SQL Command not properly ended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811711/sql-command-not-properly-ended)

Comment: Most of my aliases are 1-3 characters in length - as long as the aliases are localized (which they should all be), but I find such names appropriate. The biggest key is to be consistent with naming. (In which case `Student_Name` is awful reads as a scalar and not a relation.)

Comment: Same error: "SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: check your line breaks make sure you have spaces ie put it all on one line and make sure there is a space after "s"