# ORACLE SQL: Missing keyword

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlite

my following query provokes the error message "Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword" but works with SQLite. I can't find the error.

```
WITH subA AS (

SELECT customer.first_name, customer.last_name, customer.store_id, film_id from
    (SELECT customer_id, film_id from inventory join
        (SELECT rental.customer_id, rental.inventory_id from rental join
            (select customer_id, substr(first_name, 1, 1), substr(last_name, 1, 1) from customer where substr(first_name, 1, 1)  = substr(last_name, 1, 1)  AND customer.store_id = 2) as subResults
        on subResults.customer_id = rental.customer_id) as subResults2
    on inventory.inventory_id = subResults2.inventory_id) as finalsubR
join customer on customer.customer_id = finalsubR.customer_id

),

filmResults AS (

select * from (select title, rating, inventory.film_id, inventory_id from inventory join film on inventory.film_id = film.film_id) where rating = 'PG'

)

select distinct first_name, last_name, store_id from subA join filmResults on subA.film_id = filmResults.film_id ORDER by last_name
```

Comment: Oracle does not support `AS` for table aliases. Use `as finalsubR` instead of `as finalsubR`

Comment: What shall I change?

Comment: Sorry, copy and paste error ;) Remove the `AS` keyowrd: `finalsubR` instead of `as finalsubR`

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18718444/sql-join-subquery

Comment: Oh, this works perfectly! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,.. Oracle does not support AS for table alias.

```
WITH subA AS
       (SELECT customer.first_name
              ,customer.last_name
              ,customer.store_id
              ,film_id
        FROM   (SELECT customer_id
                      ,film_id
                FROM   inventory
                       JOIN (SELECT rental.customer_id
                                   ,rental.inventory_id
                             FROM   rental
                                    JOIN (SELECT customer_id
                                                ,SUBSTR(first_name, 1, 1)
                                                ,SUBSTR(last_name, 1, 1)
                                          FROM   customer
                                          WHERE  SUBSTR(first_name, 1, 1) = SUBSTR(last_name, 1, 1)
                                          AND    customer.store_id = 2) subResults
                                      ON subResults.customer_id = rental.customer_id) subResults2
                         ON inventory.inventory_id = subResults2.inventory_id) finalsubR
               JOIN customer ON customer.customer_id = finalsubR.customer_id)
    ,filmResults AS
       (SELECT *
        FROM   (SELECT title
                      ,rating
                      ,inventory.film_id
                      ,inventory_id
                FROM   inventory JOIN film ON inventory.film_id = film.film_id)
        WHERE  rating = 'PG')
SELECT   DISTINCT first_name
                 ,last_name
                 ,store_id
FROM     subA JOIN filmResults ON subA.film_id = filmResults.film_id
ORDER BY last_name
```