# PL/SQL ORA-00933: SQL COMMAND NOT PROPERLY ENDED

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Referring to this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811711/sql-command-not-properly-ended) 'AS' is not supported, what would be the substitution syntax to implement my with SQL command?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "LCAccountSP" (
    xReceiptType IN VARCHAR2,
    xManual IN VARCHAR2,
    xRCO IN VARCHAR2,
    xMuncID IN VA) AS
BEGIN
    CASE        
        WHEN xReceiptType = 'ROR' THEN 
            SELECT xAccount, xCount, xAmount 
            FROM (
                SELECT 
                    b.ACCT_CODE AS xAccount, 
                    COUNT(*) AS xCount, 
                    SUM(b.ROR_TOTAL_PAID) as xAmount 
                FROM tbl_tax_payment aa
                    INNER JOIN tbl_revenue_official_receipt b
                        ON aa.TPAY_RECEIPT_NO = b.TPAY_RECEIPT_NO 
                WHERE
                    aa.RECEIPT_TYPE = xReceiptType
                    AND aa.RECEIPT_MODE = xManual 
                    AND aa.LOC_NO IS NULL 
                    AND aa.RCO_CODE = xRCO 
                    AND aa.MUNC_ID = xMuncID 
                GROUP BY xAccount
            ) AS xAccount;

        WHEN xReceiptType = 'OR' THEN 
            SELECT xAccount, xCount, xAmount 
            FROM (
                SELECT b.ACCT_CODE AS xAccount,
                    COUNT(*) AS xCount,
                    SUM(b.OR_TOTAL_PAID) as xAmount  
                FROM tbl_tax_payment aa 
                    INNER JOIN tbl_official_receipt b
                    ON aa.TPAY_RECEIPT_NO = b.TPAY_RECEIPT_NO 
                WHERE aa.RECEIPT_TYPE = xReceiptType 
                    AND aa.RECEIPT_MODE = xManual 
                    AND aa.LOC_NO IS NULL 
                    AND aa.RCO_CODE = xRCO 
                    AND aa.MUNC_ID = xMuncID 
                GROUP BY xAccount
            ) AS xAccount;

        WHEN xReceiptType = 'AR' THEN 

            SELECT xAccount, xCount, xAmount
            FROM (
                SELECT b.ACCT_CODE AS xAccount,
                    COUNT(*) AS xCount,
                    SUM(b.AR_TOTAL_PAID) as xAmount  
                FROM tbl_tax_payment aa
                    INNER JOIN tbl_ack_receipt b 
                        ON aa.TPAY_RECEIPT_NO = b.TPAY_RECEIPT_NO 
                WHERE aa.RECEIPT_TYPE = xReceiptType 
                    AND aa.RECEIPT_MODE = xManual 
                    AND aa.LOC_NO IS NULL 
                    AND aa.RCO_CODE = xRCO 
                    AND aa.MUNC_ID = xMuncID 
                GROUP BY xAccount
            ) AS xAccount;
    END CASE;
END;
```

Comment: Just saw `xMuncID IN VA` I though I did this mistake, when I edited question. But when I checked my edit history I saw this issue in original code, so please check your code with proper parameter list also.

Comment: yes i also edited that.. regarding my question.. the GROUP BY xAccount from my Query i not recognized as it is from the alias..

Comment: Yes It is not possible to use pseudonym for `group by` in the same query, but it is possible to use it after subquerying it. Anyway check my code below I correct it and it seems that code should compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need delete only `AS` when you define pseudonyms of tables. Defining pseudonyms of columns with `AS` is normal. Check this example please http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/21775

**Update** also correct parameter of procedure `xMuncID IN VA` to `xMuncID IN VARCHAR2`

Try to invoke this code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "LCAccountSP" (
    xReceiptType IN VARCHAR2,
    xManual IN VARCHAR2,
    xRCO IN VARCHAR2,
    xMuncID IN VARCHAR2)
AS
    -- please check that datatypes is suite for your needs
    v_xAccount varchar2(100);
    v_xCount number;
    v_xAmount number;
BEGIN
    CASE        
        WHEN xReceiptType = 'ROR' THEN 
            SELECT xAccount, xCount, xAmount 
            INTO v_xAccount, v_xCount, v_xAmount 
            FROM (
                SELECT 
                    b.ACCT_CODE AS xAccount, 
                    COUNT(*) AS xCount, 
                    SUM(b.ROR_TOTAL_PAID) as xAmount 
                FROM tbl_tax_payment aa
                    INNER JOIN tbl_revenue_official_receipt b
                        ON aa.TPAY_RECEIPT_NO = b.TPAY_RECEIPT_NO 
                WHERE
                    aa.RECEIPT_TYPE = xReceiptType
                    AND aa.RECEIPT_MODE = xManual 
                    AND aa.LOC_NO IS NULL 
                    AND aa.RCO_CODE = xRCO 
                    AND aa.MUNC_ID = xMuncID 
                GROUP BY b.ACCT_CODE
            ) xAccount;

        WHEN xReceiptType = 'OR' THEN 
            SELECT xAccount, xCount, xAmount 
            INTO v_xAccount, v_xCount, v_xAmount 
            FROM (
                SELECT b.ACCT_CODE AS xAccount,
                    COUNT(*) AS xCount,
                    SUM(b.OR_TOTAL_PAID) as xAmount  
                FROM tbl_tax_payment aa 
                    INNER JOIN tbl_official_receipt b
                    ON aa.TPAY_RECEIPT_NO = b.TPAY_RECEIPT_NO 
                WHERE aa.RECEIPT_TYPE = xReceiptType 
                    AND aa.RECEIPT_MODE = xManual 
                    AND aa.LOC_NO IS NULL 
                    AND aa.RCO_CODE = xRCO 
                    AND aa.MUNC_ID = xMuncID 
                GROUP BY b.ACCT_CODE
            ) xAccount;

        WHEN xReceiptType = 'AR' THEN 

            SELECT xAccount, xCount, xAmount
            INTO v_xAccount, v_xCount, v_xAmount 
            FROM (
                SELECT b.ACCT_CODE AS xAccount,
                    COUNT(*) AS xCount,
                    SUM(b.AR_TOTAL_PAID) as xAmount  
                FROM tbl_tax_payment aa
                    INNER JOIN tbl_ack_receipt b 
                        ON aa.TPAY_RECEIPT_NO = b.TPAY_RECEIPT_NO 
                WHERE aa.RECEIPT_TYPE = xReceiptType 
                    AND aa.RECEIPT_MODE = xManual 
                    AND aa.LOC_NO IS NULL 
                    AND aa.RCO_CODE = xRCO 
                    AND aa.MUNC_ID = xMuncID 
                GROUP BY b.ACCT_CODE
            ) xAccount;
    END CASE;
END;
```

Comment: regarding my question.. the GROUP BY xAccount from my Query i not recognized as it is from the alias..